# FancyBox 3.3.5 Options not applying

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox

I am using fancybox 3.3.5 and I have some options set but they don't seem to apply.  Here's my HTML/CSS:

HTML (Edit includes CDNs and placeholder images for testing):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
        <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-fancybox="gallery">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/360x150" width="360" />
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Options:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".gallery").fancybox({
            defaults = {
                loop: true,
                gutter: 25,
                buttons: [
                    "fullScreen",
                    "download",
                    "thumbs",
                    "close"
                ],
                idleTime: 10,
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to replace `$(".gallery")` with correct selector as this selector would not return any element and defaults will be applied.

So, change `$(".gallery")` to `$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]')`